# overwrite a changes with = on lua require

Tags: lua, config, require

My code

```
local config = require(“storage/emulated/0/GTPSHelper/config”)
local setting = config.settings

print(setting.wrench) — yes it works when i execute it cuz it loads from config directory and it returns 1

setting.wrench = 2 — but it didnt make any changes on config files directory, it still 1
```

I appreciated for someone who help me thx, sorry for my bad grammar.

i tried

```
setting.wrench = 2 — but it doesnt make any changes on config.lua
```

here inside of my config.lua

```
local application =
{
    settings =
    {
       wrench = 1,
    },
}
return application
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to rewrite your code on chance? It modifies your `config` table, and if you want to save it, do so. Check out http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Answer (score 2):

`require` (as far as you are concerned) is a function that just reads and executes the file you specify. So when you write `require(".../config")`, you are basically reading and executing the *config.lua* file. That means that `require`ing a file would have (almost) the same result as copy-pasting its contents inside your program.

So why do you expect it to modify the file? It modifies the *table*, but that table is just the *return value* of your other script (config.lua). If you want to store the changes, you should look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization (as @Luke100000) suggested. You can think of it this way: `require` is for libraries; if you want to save and later load config data, you should either use a really simple config file format and implement the read/write yourself, or find one online, and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but try doing this:

```
local config = require("storage/emulated/0/GTPSHelper/config")
local setting = config.settings

print(setting.wrench)
package.loaded["storage/emulated/0/GTPSHelper/config"].settings.wrench = 2
print(setting.wrench)
```

Just make sure to always require the file using the same path during the same runtime, in other words, don't use relative path.

It won't persist the modification to the file, instead, it will work during runtime.
So, if other files of the program require it, then it should have the updated value.

Comment: They will have the updated value anyways as you don't load a file twice. `package.loaded["storage/emulated/0/GTPSHelper/config"].settings` is the same table as `settings`.